# Rails: Point several nested routes to one customer controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, polymorphic-associations

How do you point different nested routes to one controller action?

A user can be a member of several groups like company, project, group ect. for which It can request to join, leave or be removed by an admin.

I want to access the remove action for several models and destroy the belongs_to record in the profile model

I already have a polymorphic model that takes requests from a profile to a *model*( e.g. company) and upon acceptance of the request the profile will belong to the *model*. once the request is accepted the request recored is destroyed. I feel that the remove action that will destroy the relationship between the profile and the *model* should be part of the requests_controller, but I guess could be part of the profile_controller.

What I'm thinking I need to end up with is either

```
/_model_/:id/profile/:id/remove
/company/:id/profile/:id/remove
```

but how do I get this to point the remove action in my requests controller

or

```
/_model_/:id/requests/remove
/company/:id/request/remove
```

I am using the following code in my routes

```
resources :companies do
   resource :requests do
     put 'remove', :on => :member 
   end
   resources :requests do
      put 'accept', :on => :member
   end
 end
```

This is producing a double up of the routes

```
remove_company_requests PUT    /companies/:company_id/requests/remove(.:format)     
       company_requests POST   /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
   new_company_requests GET    /companies/:company_id/requests/new(.:format)        
  edit_company_requests GET    /companies/:company_id/requests/edit(.:format)       
                        GET    /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
                        PUT    /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
                        DELETE /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
 accept_company_request PUT    /companies/:company_id/requests/:id/accept(.:format) 
                        GET    /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
                        POST   /companies/:company_id/requests(.:format)            
    new_company_request GET    /companies/:company_id/requests/new(.:format)       
   edit_company_request GET    /companies/:company_id/requests/:id/edit(.:format)   
        company_request GET    /companies/:company_id/requests/:id(.:format)        
                        PUT    /companies/:company_id/requests/:id(.:format)        
                        DELETE /companies/:company_id/requests/:id(.:format)
```

As

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My I suggest that you create a new controller to handle this? The advantage is that you can map the route to this controller on any models you want the "remove association" on.

For example:

```
# RemoveController.rb
class RemoveController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
     # inplement the logic for deletion. You can use refection to implement 
     # this function only once for all the applied associations.    
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :companies do
  resource :requests do
    resource :remove, :controller => :remove, :only => [:destroy]
  end
end
```

The above routes would generate:

```
company_requests_remove DELETE /companies/:company_id/requests/remove(.:format)          remove#destroy
```

You can nest the above line for the remove controller on any nested routes you want and they will all point back to the RemoteController's destroy object, only with different parameters to help you implement the destroy action.

Edit: to add create for specific relationship that you don't want to duplicate you can do this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :companies do
  resource :requests do
    resource :remove, :controller => :relationship, :only => [:destroy]
    resource :create, :controller => :relationship, :only => [:create]
  end
end

company_requests_remove DELETE /companies/:company_id/requests/remove(.:format)        relationship#destroy
company_requests_create POST   /companies/:company_id/requests/create(.:format)        relationship#create
```

But I think you might need to be careful about breaking the convention of create in the respective controller. I'm not sure if there are any downside to this. The remove part since is only removing association and not the records itself, it doesn't seem to break the convention.

Comment: What would be involved in stretching that to a Relationship contoller so the a custom accept(create) action the I have in my requests controller becomes the create action

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite follow your question above. Can you clarify a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if I understand you right, let me edit the solution above and see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
puts 'remove', :on => :member, :controller => :requests, :action => :remove
```